# Google App Engine SDK deprecation effecting my Framework application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, playframework-1.x, siena

I have application which is developed in Play framework 1.x and running on Google app engine Standard Environment.
And below is the way I am deploying the application GAE.
Command- play gae:deploy
But this command internally calling "appcfg" from GAE Cloud SDK.

So now I have to change my deployment procedure.I have tried to deploy using Cloud SDK as recommended by Google Document.The base command which - "gcloud app deploy".

I have checked the Google Cloud documentation And found that they are recommend to use Java11 for GAE standard Environment with app.yaml file.

But I want to use Java8 only as of now for GAE standard env.

But while deploying its giving warning as below-

> WARNING: Automatic app detection is deprecated and will soon be removed. As an a
>   lternative, create an app.yaml file yourself using the directions at https://clo
>   ud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
>   (App Engine Flexible Environment) or https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/sta
>   ndard/python/config/appref (App Engine Standard Environment) under the tab for y
>   our language.
>   Deployment to Google App Engine requires an app.yaml file. This
>   command will run `gcloud beta app gen-config` to generate an app.yaml
>   file for you in the current directory (if the current directory does
>   not contain an App Engine service, please answer "no").

1. If I have to build app.yaml file for my java based GAE standard application what will be the structure for that?
2. If app.yaml file is not possible for java8 GAE application what will be the structure of appengine-web.xml for deploying this application using command

   ```
   "gcloud app deploy"
   ```
3. There is one more alternative is ,I should migrate the application maven based application. But right now I don't want to migrate to maven tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They explain how to migrate [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/sdk-gcloud-migration), basically get the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux) and instead of appcfg command, you’ll have to be using [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) command.

To your questions:

1 - An app.yaml is not required for Java8 Standard Environment

2 - To deploy a Java8 app with maven to GAE Standard you will use the [command](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/quickstart#deploying_and_running_hello_world_on_app_engine) `mvn appengine:deploy`

3 - This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrate-maven) explains how the migration to CloudSDK based Maven plugin. And [this one](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrate-gradle) explains the migration to Cloud SDK based Gradle plugin